# OpenGL color overlay

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl, transparency

I want to create a pause menu where everything in the background gets darker. I've looked up a bunch of possible solutions (even the second page on google) but it doesn't seem to work. I do already have something in my code that makes a single texture darker when hovered over, by calling: `GL11.glColor3f(alpha, alpha, alpha);` before drawing vertices. What I want to achieve is everything getting darker, so when hovering over a texture it should be even darker than before so it is still darker than the rest in the background when that has been made darker because of a pause menu that pops up.

Another thing I noticed is that `glColorMask(true, false, false, true);` does not get overridden and blends colours everywhere, so I was wondering if there is a version of this method that puts a transparent black overlay so everything becomes darker. I have enabled blending.

-Edit-

One solution I came up with (not just now) is multiplying `alpha` in every glColor3f function with a variable that is smaller than 1 so everthing gets relatively smaller, but I worry about this being uneffective and badly mantainable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GL11.glColor3f(alpha, alpha, alpha);` won't work for 2 reasons:

1. It's opaque.  You'd need `GL11.glColor4f(alpha, alpha, alpha,alpha);`
2. It affects the *next* object to be rendered, not everything *already* rendered.

It would be easier to render a semi-transparent quad over the whole screen (with a slightly higher z-depth) prior to drawing the menu.  This will cut down on the amount of code necessary to achieve the effect, GPU-time its probably slightly worse, but only slightly.

Comment: I now call this method before drawing anything but it doesn't appear: `public static void DrawQuad(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
  glColor4f(.3f, .3f, .3f, .3f);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glVertex3f(x, y, 1); //Top left corner
  glVertex3f(x + width, y, 1); //Top right corner
  glVertex3f(x + width, y + height, 1); //Bottom right corner
  glVertex3f(x, y + height, 1); //Bottom left corner
  glEnd();
 }` For all the other things I use glVertex2f does that have something to do with it?

Comment: I would have to check my own quad-drawing code, which is on another computer.  I practically stole Minecraft's GUI setup and Tessellator "GL-helper" class.  It was a much cleaner way of doing the menus than what I'd been doing in Unity prior (second camera in orthographic mode).  It was a huge hassle to translate the calls, though.  Not as much GL access as in Java.